# Specifying a path to imakeidx

Tags: imakeidx

When compiling, my auxiliary files are placed in a separate folder. How do I tell imakeidx to look in that folder? Currently I have to manually move the .idx file to the same folder as the .tex file in order for it to produce an index. Also, in that case it will place the .ilg and .ind files in this folder rather than the folder with rest of the auxiliary files.

Comment: It's not currently possible, sorry. I'm not sure if this is a feature I'd like to add: it requires correct interaction with `makeindex` and `splitindex`; I'm unsure about the second program, mainly.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/206695/latexmk-outdir-with-include#comment481933_206695

Comment: I have the same problem. @egreg Does there exists a solution now? I don't really care about splitindex, but it would be nice if texindy would be called in the right path.