# Create Glossaries within TeX Studio with Intermediate Files in a Custom Directory

Tags: glossaries

## Goal

I am trying to create a glossary with the following MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\loadglsentries{foo}
\begin{document}

\gls{foobar} is a strange animal

\gls{foo} is another strange animal
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

where the glossary items reside in a separate `foo.tex`:

```latex
\newglossaryentry{foobar}{%
  name={Foobar},
  description={A strange animal, not to be confused with \gls{foo}}
}

\newglossaryentry{foo}{%
  name={Foo},
  description={A strange animal, not to be confused with \gls{foobar}}
}
```

## Difficulty

The unique thing I have is I put all intermediate files (for example, `.aux`) into a separate `build/` directory, which makes my directory looks like the following:

```bash
.
├── build
├── foo.tex
└── test.tex
```

The following are the commands I use

- `xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape -output-directory=build %.tex`
- `makeglossaries build/%`
- Build & View: `txs:///compile | txs:///makeglossaries | txs:///compile | txs:///view`

However, I observed the following

- When I pressed `F5`, no glossaries were generated and the following error messages prompted:

```bash
Process started: makeglossaries build/"test"

***Call to makeindex failed*** Possible cause of problem: Style file not found. (Have you used \noist by mistake?) Check 'build/test.glg' for details
Process exited with error(s)


Process started: xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape -output-directory=build "test".tex

Index style file test.ist not found. Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]
system returned with code 256
Process exited normally
```

- When I went into the `build/` directory, `makeglossaries test`, and then `F5`, the glossaries could be generated but error messages persisted.

Did I set use the `makeglossaries` command incorrectly? What do I have to do to resolve this issue?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/206695/latexmk-outdir-with-include#comment481933_206695

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So are you saying that it is not possible to resolve the problem? I do find putting the intermediate files in a separate directory useful so I could put the entire directory into `.gitignore` for version control.

Comment: Oh I'm sure it's possible, just that personally I wouldn't. It complicates the process enormously. you might need three or four extra lines in gitigore, or to make your build script move stuff after the build but either likely to be easier than using output-directory