# Is it possible to get the value of --output-directory programmatically from LaTeX code?

Tags: external-files

I'm trying to save a file first, using `\VerbatimOut`. Then, I'm using this file in `\ShellEscape`, where I need to know its absolute path name. Everything works well, until `--output-directory` is changed and `\VerbatimOut` saves the file to a location different from current directory. How can I get the value of `--output-directory`?

p.s. I guess, it's not possible, since this is what [`minted`](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf) says:

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/206695/latexmk-outdir-with-include#comment481933_206695

Answer (score 1):

In Linux you can search the list of currently running processes using the command `ps aux`. For me an entry of `pdflatex` with `--output-dir` looks like this:

```
marijn     94217  0.0  0.2 119940 40784 pts/1    S+   18:22   0:00 pdflatex --shell-escape --output-dir=diffout chkoutdir.tex
```

Then you can pattern match for an entry containing `latex` and `--output-dir`, and then capture what comes after the equals sign.

MWE:

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{shellesc}
\begin{document}
\begin{VerbatimOut}{verbfile.txt}
I write that. And that too.
\end{VerbatimOut}
\ShellEscape{bash chkdirscript.sh}
\end{document}
```

Script:

```bash
if ps aux|pcregrep -q "latex.*[-]output-dir=[^ ]+ "; then
    OUTDIR=$(ps aux|pcregrep -o1 "latex.*[-]output-dir=([^ ]+) ")
    cat $OUTDIR/verbfile.txt
else
    cat verbfile.txt
fi
```

Compiling the LaTeX document will now show the contents of the file in the terminal both in situations where the `--output-dir` flag is used and in situations where it is not used.

This does not work if the output directory contains spaces. It also may not work if the specified output directory is itself a call to a script or variable of some sort. Furthermore it may not work if there is more than one instance of LaTeX running. So I don't recommend it for actual use, just a proof of concept.